# modules on xslt 1.0

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I am trying to use the regex module of xslt but I am getting an error saying that the `function match not found`. 
I understand that I need to get the files that contains that function, but I can´t find it because all the download links here: http://exslt.org/regexp/index.html are down.

Any one knows where can I download from??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which XSLT 1 processor exactly do you use? There is no magic support for EXSLT, some stuff can be implemented in XSLT with templates itself but I don't think anyone has done that for regular expressions. So whether you can use those extension functions depends on whether the XSLT processor has an extension library for that stuff or someone has written one, like http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/regexp.match.msxsl.xsl for MSXML.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen I am really newbie with xslt. I only know that I use `xsltproc` command line to run it. I think it uses `libxml2`... I hope it helps to know the xslt processor. Thanks in advance (again).

Comment: Looking at http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/EXSLT/html/libexslt-exslt.html it doesn't seem that libxslt/xsltproc supports the regular expression module of EXSLT so unless there is some third party extension somewhere else I think you are out of luck.

Comment: I suggest you post a question with the real problem. XSLT 1.0 is Turing-complete, so there should be a way to achieve your goal even without using regex.

Comment: @MartinHonnen this is a bad news, but there is nothing we can do. Thanks for all.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k yes... I am doing in a different way, but I would want to improve it using regex. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Saxon 9.8 HE C (http://saxonica.com/download/c.xml) is available on most platforms now where you can compile C/C++ and it supports XSLT 3 with standardized regular expression function support like `tokenize`, `matches`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match. So that would be an option, to move from 20 year old XSLT 1 to modern XSLT 3.